# Join lists and compare

Tags: c#, list, join

I am really hoping for help here. I am trying to make a cardgame like Rummy and has gotten real far, but...

When a player can't lay down some cards on the board, the player have the opportunity to either pass or swap some cards. The game persists of 2 decks of cards (104 cards) and each player gets 12 cards from start. The anatomy of the cards in the decks are like this:

**color,number,id**

All cards are in the decks in one long string like so:

**r,1,1,r,1,2,r,2,3,r,2,4..... etc**

The players cards are in an inventory with a placement attached like this:

**placement,color,number,id**

**1,b,9,17,2,r,6,34.....etc.**

The cards on the table/board is like this:

**placement,color,number,id**

**a1,y,7,65,a2,y,8,67.... etc**

So each inventory, card decks and table cards are in comma separated strings and has to stay this way (sorry).

Now, here is how I am trying to ensure that I don't get to many of one kind in my game, but with little luck. Sometimes I get to many cards in the game, ex 3 #13 of the same color. But here is my current script for this:

```
// PLAYERCARDS //
playercardsArray = playercards.Split (","[0]);

q = 0;
m = "";
foreach(string thisvalue in playercardsArray){
    m += (q%4 == 3)?thisvalue+';':thisvalue+','; 
    q++;
}

playercardsArray = m.Split (";"[0]);

foreach(string thisCard in playercardsArray){
    playercardsList.Add(thisCard);
}

playercardsList.RemoveAt(playercardsList.Count-1); 

foreach(string remcards in playercardsList){
    joinedList.Add(remcards.Substring(remcards.IndexOf(",") + 1));
}


// OPPCARDS //
oppcardsArray = oppcards.Split (","[0]);

q = 0;
m = "";
foreach(string thisvalue in oppcardsArray){
    m += (q%4 == 3)?thisvalue+';':thisvalue+','; 
    q++;
}

oppcardsArray = m.Split (";"[0]);

foreach(string thisCard in oppcardsArray){
    oppcardsList.Add(thisCard);
}

oppcardsList.RemoveAt(oppcardsList.Count-1); 

foreach(string remcards in oppcardsList){
    joinedList.Add(remcards.Substring(remcards.IndexOf(",") + 1));
}

// BOARDCARDS //
boardcardsArray = tabletiles.Split (","[0]);

q = 0;
m = "";
foreach(string thisvalue in boardcardsArray){
    m += (q%4 == 3)?thisvalue+';':thisvalue+','; 
    q++;
}

boardcardsArray = m.Split (";"[0]);

foreach(string thisCard in boardcardsArray){
    boardcardsList.Add(thisCard);
}

boardcardsList.RemoveAt(boardcardsList.Count-1); 

foreach(string remcards in boardcardsList){
    joinedList.Add(remcards.Substring(remcards.IndexOf(",") + 1));
}

// NEWCARDS //
newcardsArray = newcards.Split (","[0]);

q = 0;
m = "";
foreach(string thisvalue in newcardsArray){
    m += (q%4 == 3)?thisvalue+';':thisvalue+','; 
    q++;
}

newcardsArray = m.Split (";"[0]);

foreach(string thisCard in newcardsArray){
    newcardsList.Add(thisCard);
}

newcardsList.RemoveAt(newcardsList.Count-1); 

foreach(string remcards in newcardsList){
    joinedList.Add(remcards.Substring(remcards.IndexOf(",") + 1));
}

// ALLCARDS //
cardsArray = new string[]{ "r,1,1","r,1,2","r,2,3","r,2,4","r,3,5","r,3,6","r,4,7","r,4,8","r,5,9","r,5,10","r,6,11","r,6,12","r,7,13","r,7,14","r,8,15","r,8,16","r,9,17","r,9,18","r,10,19","r,10,20","r,11,21","r,11,22","r,12,23","r,12,24","r,13,25","r,13,26","b,1,27","b,1,28","b,2,29","b,2,30","b,3,31","b,3,32","b,4,33","b,4,34","b,5,35","b,5,36","b,6,37","b,6,38","b,7,39","b,7,40","b,8,41","b,8,42","b,9,43","b,9,44","b,10,45","b,10,46","b,11,47","b,11,48","b,12,49","b,12,50","b,13,51","b,13,52","y,1,53","y,1,54","y,2,55","y,2,56","y,3,57","y,3,58","y,4,59","y,4,60","y,5,61","y,5,62","y,6,63","y,6,64","y,7,65","y,7,66","y,8,67","y,8,68","y,9,69","y,9,70","y,10,71","y,10,72","y,11,73","y,11,74","y,12,75","y,12,76","y,13,77","y,13,78","g,1,79","g,1,80","g,2,81","g,2,82","g,3,83","g,3,84","g,4,85","g,4,86","g,5,87","g,5,88","g,6,89","g,6,90","g,7,91","g,7,92","g,8,93","g,8,94","g,9,95","g,9,96","g,10,97","g,10,98","g,11,99","g,11,100","g,12,101","g,12,102","g,13,103","g,13,104"};
q = 0;

foreach(string thisCard in cardsArray){
    cardsList.Add(thisCard);
}

foreach (string s in joinedList){
    cardsList.Remove(s);
}

thedecks = "";
thedecks = string.Join(",", cardsList.ToArray());
```

I know this is quite a bit, and it problary can be done a whole lot smarter, so I am hoping for help in this matter. I have tried so many times now but with no luck

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What is the question exactly? Is it not doing something you want it to?

Comment: Please update your sample to use strongly typed objects instead of strings so it is easier to read. And add actual question instead of "tried so many times now but with no luck".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Read the OP's post "So each inventory, card decks and table cards are in comma separated strings and has to stay this way (sorry)."  Homework is meant to be challenging ;-)

Comment: From time to time it fails to join correctly. I some times get more cards than 104, meaning triples of some of the cards. @AlexeiLevenkov - Not sure what you mean :-/

Comment: @snafu918 - got it... cleaning streets with toothpicks...

Comment: Does this all boil down to the fact that `cardsList` ends up with more than 104 cards?

Comment: No, the cardlist should be smaller and smaller as the game progress, but the players cards and the cards on the table and the cardlist should be 104 all together and there should only be lets say 2 yellow #3 in all the cards. Hope this makes sense :-/